# How to retrieve member fields from nested classes recursively in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nested-class

I am calling a method `GetEmployee()` which returns the value of type `Employee` and stored in `emp` variable.

```
var emp = GetEmployee();
```

I need to retrieve all the member fields of the Employee class like age, name and also members of nested classes like

```
[Address->DoorNum,Street,Zip]
[Phone->mobile,homePhone],
[Dependents->name,age,
[phone->mobile,homePhone]]
```

recursively from the `emp` variable.

The class structure is as below:

```
class Employee
{
 int age;
 string name
 Address address;
 Phone[] phones;
 Dependents[] dependents;
}

class Address
{
 int DoorNum;
 string Street;
 int Zip;
}

class Phone
{
 string mobile;
 string homePhone;
}

class Dependents
{
 string name;
 int age;
 Phone depPhone;
}
```

Can you help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: can you provide more context for what you want to do? there are numerous ways to solve this from rolling your own to 3rd party libraries. what you want to do with the data will have an impact on how you do it.

Comment: Are you wanting to Create an Employee object or just pull out the variables? or do you want to get the Property Names at runtime? I'm not too sure what your exactly asking for.

Comment: That's not referred to as `Recursion`.

Comment: Some web service request returning the value of type Employee. And I have the same class structure as I mentioned above. I need to create one Employee object which contains returned values.

Comment: public Employee getEmployee()
{
var emp=EmployeeProxy.Employee();
return new Employee
{
name=emp.name,
age=emp.age,
dependents=emp.DependentsType.Select(d=>new Dependents{name=d.Name,age=d.Age,..}
}
}
Like this I'm going to take the values. But I'm not able to retrieve  Phone inside Dependents. Its giving values only one level from Employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer for my question:

```
public Employee getEmployee() 
{
    var emp=EmployeeProxy.GetEmployee();         
    return new Employee {        
    name=emp.Name,         
        age=emp.Age,         
        address=emp.AddressType.Select(a=>new Address{        
             DoorNum=a.doorNum,        
             Street=ae.street,        
             Zip=a.zip,        
        }),        
        phones=new Phone[]{        
             mobile=PhoneType.Mobile,        
             homePhone=PhoneType.HomePhone,        
        },        
        dependents=emp.DependentsType.Select(d=>new Dependents{        
             name=d.Name,        
             age=d.Age,        
             depPhone=new Phone{        
                     mobile=d.DependentPhone.Mobile,        
                     homePhone=d.DependentPhone.HomePhone,        
             },        
        }),         
    }; //End of Return        
} //End of method
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are talking about dynamically retrieving fields at runtime, here is a simple recursive example intended for illustration more than utilitiy. Note that by default class fields are inferred to be private.

```
public static void listFields(Type type, bool sameNamespace, int nestLevel = 1) {
    BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n{0}Fields of {1}:", tabs(nestLevel - 1), type.Name);
    foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields(bf)) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2} {3}", tabs(nestLevel), (f.IsPublic ? "public" : "private"), f.FieldType.Name, f.Name);
        Type fieldType = (f.FieldType.IsArray) ? f.FieldType.GetElementType() : f.FieldType;
        if ((type != fieldType) && (!sameNamespace || fieldType.Namespace == type.Namespace)) {
            listFields(fieldType, sameNamespace, nestLevel + 2);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private static String tabs(int count) { return new String(' ', count * 3); }
```

Output of `listFields(typeof(Employee), true);`:

```
Fields of Employee:
   private Int32 age
   private String name
   private Address address

      Fields of Address:
         private Int32 DoorNum
         private String Street
         private Int32 Zip

   private Phone[] phones

      Fields of Phone:
         private String mobile
         private String homePhone

   private Dependents[] dependents

      Fields of Dependents:
         private String name
         private Int32 age
         private Phone depPhone

            Fields of Phone:
               private String mobile
               private String homePhone
```

If you wanted to actually get the value of a field of an instance, you would use [`FieldInfo.GetValue(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)